# Request ADFS security token from the backend of single sign-on enabled ASP.NET website

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have a single sign-on enabled ASP.NET web site which uses ADFS for authentication. On logon users are redirected to the ADFS sign-in page, then my application gets FedAuth cookies back and doesn't store any user passwords.

What I need to do is to contact a third-party service (namely, SharePoint), which is configured to use the same ADFS server for authentication, from the web site backend. I've learned that I should be able to do so by getting another security token using some WIF (WCF in fact) calls described for example here http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.

My problem is I don't know how to provide authentication for such calls using the information implicitly available in single sign-on cookies. I do not have explicit credentials nor Windows authentication.

The code I'm trying to use follows:

```
WSTrust13ContractClient trustClient = new WSTrust13ContractClient(binding, address);

trustClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
trustClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
trustClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message response =
        trustClient.EndIssue(trustClient.BeginIssue(
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(
            MessageVersion.Default, WSTrust13Constants.Actions.Issue,
            new RequestBodyWriter(trustSerializer, rst)), null, null));
```

It fails with "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'" message.

Comment: The error you mention is also described in the blog post you link to in your question. Did you do the workaround they suggest?

Comment: The problem is, workaround applies to IIS, but in my case I have ADFS 3.0 which is no longer based on IIS, so I don't even know what to do with that